# Sets of natural numbers which are almost closed under addition

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics

I am interested in a classification of sets $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \in A$, $d( A+k \cap \mathbb{N} \setminus A) = 0$ where $d$ is the asymptotic density and $A+k = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : n-k \in A\}$. Sets with this condition are in a sense almost closed under addition. Some examples are sets of the form $C \setminus N$ where $C$ is closed under addition and $N$ has density $0$. Any set of density $0$ or $1$ also satisfies this property.

I hoped this condition was equivalent to $d(A \triangle C) = 0$ for some set $C$ closed under addition, but $A = 2 \mathbb{N} \cup \{1\}$ is a counterexample.

Is there some nice additive combinatorics classification of such sets?

Comment: Am I missing something? if $A = 2 \mathbb{N} \cup \{1\}$, then $A+1 \cap \mathbb{N} \setminus A$ is just the odd numbers greater than $1$, whose asymptotic density is obviously $1/2$. So $A$ is not one of your sets.

Comment: Right, $2\mathbb{N}\cup \{1\}$ is an example of a set which differs from a set closed under addition by a set of density zero, but which is not almost closed under addition itself. So while you can remove sets of density zero, you can't necessarily add them in.

Comment: So what I was missing is that you were giving an example in the opposite direction than I expected. mea culpa.